# ASP access database dynamic output

Tags: asp.net, database, ms-access, output

```
        <%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false 
      CodeFile="Customers.aspx.vb"                    
    Inherits="Customers" %>

         <%@ Import Namespace="System.Data" %>
         <%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.OleDb" %>
        <!DOCTYPE html>


       <script runat="server">

  </script>
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head runat="server">
   <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
 <div>

  <asp:Label runat="server" Text="By Contact Name: " />  <asp:TextBox ID="Textb" 
   runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
   <asp:DataGrid runat="server" ID="out" DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1" />
    <asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource1" runat="server" 
        DataFile="~/App_Data/northwind.mdb" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Customers] WHERE ([ContactName] = ?)">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="Textb" Name="ContactName"  
    PropertyName="Text" 
                Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:AccessDataSource>
    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="By Company Name: " />  <asp:TextBox 
    ID="Texta" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>

    <br />
   <asp:DataGrid runat="server" ID="out0" DataSourceID="AccessDataSource2" />
    <asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource2" runat="server" 
        DataFile="~/App_Data/northwind.mdb" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Customers] WHERE ([CompanyName] = ?)">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="Texta" 
         Name="CompanyName" PropertyName="Text" 
                Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:AccessDataSource>

 </div>
 </form>
   </body>
 </html>
```

Guys, I am trying to create kind of ... dynamic output meaning: I have a database and I want to search it and display the output in the format above. The thing is:
1. When I do not have the second textbox and dataGrid I get output by the search I do but I still need to hit enter. How do I make it so it automatically displays result while i am writing the search itself. I have in mind something like onchangedtext event if you get me.
2. When I add the datagrid I do not get any output even if I hit enter on the first(Name search). How do I fix that?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must write javascript code, in order to ensure that you don't postback data, because it's very expensive.

For disable just add style hidden on cells.

I suggest this post (Similar case with color) : http://csharp-guide.blogspot.fr/2012/07/aspnet-jquery-gridview-filter.html